# Using Scorer Object for Classifier Score Method for scikit-learn

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn

I have written my custom scorer object which is necessary for my problem and which I've called "p_value_scoring_object".

For the function sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score one of the parameters is "scoring", which allows to use this scorer object.

However, this option is not available for the score method of a classifier. Is sklearn just lacking that feature, or is there a way around it?

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.cross_validation import cross_val_score
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)
iris = load_iris()
cross_val_score(clf, iris.data, iris.target, cv=10,scoring=p_value_scoring_object)
```

This works. However, this doesn't:

```
clf.fit(iris.data,iris.target)
clf.score(iris.data,iris.target,scoring=p_value_scoring_object)
```

Answer (score 1):

Why should it work? `scoring` is an argument of [cross_val_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score.html#sklearn.cross_validation.cross_val_score), not [score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.score). The documentation says `score` "returns the mean accuracy on the given test data and labels." This behavior is not specific to `DecisionTreeClassifier`, but common to classifiers in sklearn.

Perhaps you want [sklearn.metrics](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#classification-metrics)?